# Bootstrap 3 float layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem creating a relative simple layout. I use Bootstrap 3 but is not a must.

So, the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>a</p>
            <p>a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>b</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>c</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>d</p>
            <p>d</p>
            <p>d</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for visual purpose, the CSS:

```
div.col-md-4, div.col-md-8 { border: 1px solid red; }
```

I want that on medium screens (md) this layout (no matter of their height and without white spaces between them):

```
A B
C D
```

On small screens (sm) this kind of layout:

```
A
B
C
D
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/HxZ35/2/

Thank you!

Comment: You're putting it all in one row. Try putting A B and C D in different `.row`'s

Comment: do you want columns on same level have the same heigth?

Comment: No, columns have different heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/HxZ35/5/

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>a</p>
        <p>a</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>b</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 a">
        <p>c</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 d">
        <p>d</p>
        <p>d</p>
        <p>d</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
div.col-md-4, div.col-md-8 { border: 1px solid red; }
.a {clear: left;}
.d{float: initial; overflow:hidden;}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
.pull-right-lg { float: right !important; } 
}
```

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for because my problem was not on the  sm layout, it was on md one. I needed something to remove the white spaces between divs no matter how long is their content. Thank you chyupa.

Answer (score 1):

you need to say bootstrap that the column width on small devices is 12 `col-sm-12` otherwise the width you want for medium devices like `col-md-4`.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <p>a</p>
        <p>a</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
        <p>b</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <p>c</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8">
        <p>d</p>
        <p>d</p>
        <p>d</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think you want to do this..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>b</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>c</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>d</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/124248